# Cleanup URL for a custom page in wordpress

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

I have a wordpress website in which I have a specific page for dictionary. This page is actually a custom page and does these things:

- `site.com/dictionary` lists all the words
- `site.com/dictionary/?w=word` shows the definition of the word

now I want the URL to be cleaned up and becomes like this:

```
site.com/dictionary/word
```

I have made these lines in `.htaccess` but I get `404` error:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /dictionary/
    RewriteRule (.*) ?w=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

May you help me with this?

update:

I have tried the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162489/ but this also didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the internal rewrite system, which is parsed in php, not htaccess.

First, add the rule. This assumes you have created a root page under `Pages` with the slug `dictionary`.

```
function wpd_dictionary_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_tag( '%dictionary_word%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^dictionary/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=dictionary&dictionary_word=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_dictionary_rewrite' );
```

This code would go in your theme's `functions.php` file, or your own plugin.

Visit the `Settings > Permalinks` page to flush rules after adding this.

Now you can visit `site.com/dictionary/word` and the requested word will be available in the template with `get_query_var('dictionary_word')`.

If the code relies on `$_GET['w']` and you can't / don't want to change this, you can hook before the code runs and set the value manually:

```
function wpd_set_dictionary_word(){
    if( false !== get_query_var( 'dictionary_word', false ) ){
        $_GET['w'] = get_query_var( 'dictionary_word' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'wpd_set_dictionary_word' );
```

Comment: Tnx. But what do you mean I should flush rules in `settings > Permalinks`? I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27164024/5826526) already (without flushing Permalinks) and it didn't work. Any further input? Also, can I put these codes in the relevant page itself not in `function.php`? Everything is managed in a single template file.

Comment: Visiting the Permalinks Settings page causes WordPress to flush the cache of rewrite rules. If you add/change rules and don't flush the cache, they won't work. You have to put this code in a file that gets loaded before `init`, the simplest is `functions.php`. Template files won't work, they don't get loaded until much later.

Comment: I put the rewrite function and action into `function.php` file. I flush Permalinks as well. I prefer to use `get_query_var`. I don't get 404 error anymore (which I guess means rewrite is in action). But still I cannot get the value or the variable by `get_query_var`.

Comment: I found the problem: I was using `w` as the key for query string and by changing it into `term` the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just rewrite the URL.

You would need to refactor a lot code when using that other URL path `/word` over an URL parameter `?w=word`.

That are two different pairs of shoes...

**some more info:**

Routing with PHP in WordPress is a complex topic and not easy to describe in a few words. Even as an experienced developer, you probably won't want to be confronted with routing problems.

Here there is a short example on how PHP routing can work: https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/

Comment: Why is it so? any reference? why isn't it possible to use htaccess in wordpress?

Comment: you can use htaccess. but your problem is a different. i did add some more info to my post

Comment: what if I rewrite to `index.php?page_id=1234&w=word`? I have written `RewriteRule ^diction/(.+)$ diction/?w=$1 [L,R]` and it works with redirecting to the page. but if I remove flag R, I get 404. why is it happening? I don't want to go for php routing if I can do it with htaccess